# yii csqldataprovider not getting full items from database

Tags: php, yii

```
             $sql= "SELECT p.id, p.item_name, p.status, p.img_1, p.date_created
                    FROM user_posted_assets p
                    WHERE `p`.`status` = 'AVAILABLE'
                    ORDER BY `p`.`date_created` DESC";

             $sql_count="SELECT count(*), p.id, p.userid, p.img_1,p.date_created, p.date_lastmodified     FROM user_posted_assets p
                    WHERE `p`.`status` = 'AVAILABLE'
                    ORDER BY `p`.`date_created` DESC";

            // Get the count for
            $count=Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql_count)->queryScalar();               

            $dataProvider=new CSqlDataProvider($sql, array(
            'totalItemCount'=>$count 
            ));


           $dataset = $dataProvider->getData();

           header('content-type: application/json');

           echo CJSON::encode($dataset);
```

If i run $sql query in mysql it will show 73 rows but when i do print_r $dataset it will show only 11 items in console......

Comment: I'm sorry but your code is form Yii1 or Yii2 and if is from Yii i know sqlDataProvider i  but not  CSqlDataProvider please show al the code of this controllerAction ..

Comment: what's result of your `$count`?

Comment: i am using yii1.1  this is the full code i am using in controller.

Comment: $count result is 73.

Comment: Can you try `$count = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (' . $sql . ') as count')->queryScalar();` and see does it makes any difference?

Comment: i tried again it showing count result 73.

Comment: Try this:
 
`$dataProvider=new CSqlDataProvider($sql, array(
            'totalItemCount'=>$count,
            'pagination'=>array(
                'pageSize'=>$count
             ),
       ));`

Comment: Wow it's working now thank you so much...........

Comment: Great!. Let rephrase it in Answer to help someone else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count($provider->getData())` or `print_r $dataset` will display according to your pagination by default its 10. Either you can set pagination or remove it will work fine. When pagination is set false, this returns the same value as `totalItemCount`